# Does every person have unique nervous system?

Tags: neuroscience, peripheral-nervous-system

If we had the technology to directly interface electronic devices with the nervous system and we wanted to connect a robotic arm to a person that lost his/her real arm, would we be able to find the same "wires" that control(led) that arm in every person?

Or does every human control their organs in completely unique, "incompatible" way?

Answer (score 23):

Probably the best way to answer this question is with a counterexample to humans: the nematode worm [*C. elegans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caenorhabditis_elegans) has 302 neurons. Every individual has exactly that number, and each is found in the same place with the same function in every individual. This is one of the things that makes *C. elegans* an attractive model organism for study.

Humans definitely do not develop the same way. There are certainly *groups* of neurons that are found in every individual, and many of the tracts have at least a typical anatomical course that can be found from individual to individual, but it's not as if you can arrange each of the tens of billions of neurons in a list and find the same "Neuron #10,934,035,587" in two different people.

The most successful prosthetic operation that interfaces with the neuromuscular system these days is through [myoelectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthesis#Myoelectric) control, where rather than using electrical activity from neurons, one uses electrical activity in muscles, such as muscles in the chest and shoulder to control a prosthetic arm or hand.

Comment: But when they do things like hand transplants, they connect the patient's nerves to the nerves in the transplanted limb, don't they? People are similar enough for this to be feasible.

Comment: @Barmar They can connect *nerves*, but not neurons. The individual neurons need to re-grow through the nerve structure. "Re-wiring" the hand from that point onward is a result of extensive physical therapy and more about plasticity in the CNS than rewiring in the periphery. A similar process would happen if a nerve were severed and reattached in the same patient without a transplant; it's also somewhat similar to how those connections are developed in the first place. Human infants are born with fairly incomplete motor control and so are an (adorable) excellent insight into this.

Comment: The OP didn't specify individual neurons. I think his figurative "wires" equates to nerves.

Comment: (it's also worth noting that a lot of hand control occurs outside the hand)

Comment: @Barmar That's possible, but then you'd have to also specify the detail of nerve. Everyone has a spinal cord where nerves leave at every vertebral level, sure; from there, variation increases the more distal you get. Hooking things up at the nerve level isn't sufficient to connect electrical devices to the nervous system; the only way to do it is to let the nervous system learn associations with the connections you've made. Every attempted brain-machine-interface or nerve-machine-interface has done this.

Comment: My thinking is that the details are unique like fingerprints, but at a higher level it's similar like the general structure of fingers.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but isn't it a bit superficially obvious that if you have a finger, it has to have nervous innervation? "People have fingers" is enough to tell you that; the interesting part would be considering whether there is some one-to-one relationship between the neurons and structure of the finer nerve endings in two people; there isn't.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that the arteries and veins have direct correspondences that allow you to connect these, and there would be similar correspondences for nerves. There will be minute differences, but not enough to prevent reconnection.

Comment: @Barmar Only at a very gross level. For example see this question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82918/coronary-circulation/ about a common difference in the coronary circulation, and that's in a couple of **major** vessels together supplying over half of the blood to the heart. Have a look at the superficial veins in your arm that are quite visible from the surface: you'll find they vary quite a lot.

Comment: agreed yes you can connect the same nerves but neuron to neuron will be slightly different, especially in the brain, but the person can learn to control the new limb without problem it will just take time.  translpantees will have gross control fairly quickly but precision control takes a long time.

Comment: WRT C. elegans, neurons are actually a fairly high level of nervous system organization.  Neurons have many dendrites (IIRC something like 1-10K branches in humans) & many synapses whose state changes due to synaptic plasticity.  And researchers keep finding more low-level complexity: https://www.quantamagazine.org/neural-dendrites-reveal-their-computational-power-20200114/